# Android findViewById возвращает null

Tags: java, android

Мой код в `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

```
LayoutInflater factory = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View main_buttons_layout_view = factory.inflate(R.layout.main_buttons_layout, null);
    View side_buttons_layout_view = factory.inflate(R.layout.side_buttons_layout, null);

    flipperUp = (Button) side_buttons_layout_view.findViewById(R.id.flipperUpButton);
    flipperDown = (Button) side_buttons_layout_view.findViewById(R.id.flipperDownButton);
    shortcut1Button = (Button) side_buttons_layout_view.findViewById(R.id.shortcutButton1);
    shortcut2Button = (Button) side_buttons_layout_view.findViewById(R.id.shortcutButton2);
```

Моя разметка в **main_buttons_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

...

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/flipperDownButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:background="@drawable/flippernavigationbuttonstyle"
    android:text="down"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

...
```

Почему `flipperDown` всегда **null**? При том, что остальные кнопки из того же лейаута прекрасно инициализируются

Comment: Возможно дело то и не в разметке

Comment: А в чем же тогда?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
flipperDown = (Button) side_buttons_layout_view.findViewById(R.id.flipperDownButton);
```

поменяй на

```
flipperDown = (Button) main_buttons_layout_view.findViewById(R.id.flipperDownButton);
```

вы его ищете в другом макете

Comment: Недоглядел XD Спасибо